# Animation on togglable switch

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to add an animation to my toggleable switches but can't figure out how it works. I am trying to get it to slide over to yes or no when clicked. I am not really sure if the animations are possible with this type of html setup based on my reading online.

Html:

```
<div class="rds-toggle-switch">
<div class="rds-toggle">
    <label>
       <input type="radio" name="toggle" checked/>
       <div class="rds-toggle-header input-checked">Yes</div>
   </label>    
 </div>
    <div class="rds-toggle">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="toggle"/>
            <div class="rds-toggle-header">No</div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rds-toggle-switch{
    background: #ebebeb;
    padding-left: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #898989;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.rds-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: blue;
    width: calc(50% - 3px);
}

.rds-toggle label {
    width: 100%;
}

.rds-toggle label .rds-toggle-header {
    text-align:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:36px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.rds-toggle label .rds-toggle-subtext{
    font-size: .7857142857em;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.rds-toggle label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

.rds-toggle .input-checked {
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:#000;
    border: 1px solid #2e51a1;
    background-color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.rds-toggle').click(function(){
    var $ele = $(this);
    $ele.children('label').children('div').addClass('input-checked');
    $ele.siblings('.rds-toggle').children('label').children('div').removeClass('input-checked');
    $ele.children('label').children('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

or 
http://jsfiddle.net/cou1u6us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a slide like that because you're using two different elements - basically, you'd need a kind of a morphing so when one element starts leaving the area, the other one starts appearing, etc... It might get complicated.

Instead I suggest you use a single element to denote the active switch state, something like this - it uses an absolutely positioned "switch state" (`#rds-state`) element which is animated using CSS transitions (animating its `left` property):

```js
$('.rds-toggle').click(function() {
  var $ele = $(this);
  $('#rds-state').css('left', $ele[0].offsetLeft);
  $ele.children('label').children('div').addClass('input-checked');
  $ele.siblings('.rds-toggle').children('label').children('div').removeClass('input-checked');
  $ele.children('label').children('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```css
.rds-toggle-switch {
  background: #ebebeb;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #898989;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.rds-toggle {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  width: calc(50% - 3px);
}
.rds-toggle label {
  width: 100%;
}
.rds-toggle label .rds-toggle-header {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
}
.rds-toggle label .rds-toggle-subtext {
  font-size: .7857142857em;
  color: #ccc;
  line-height: 0.8;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.rds-toggle label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
.rds-toggle .input-checked {
  color: #000;
}
#rds-state {
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #2e51a1;
  background-color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
  transition: left 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rds-toggle-switch">
  <div id="rds-state"></div>
  <div class="rds-toggle">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="toggle" checked/>
      <div class="rds-toggle-header input-checked">Yes</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="rds-toggle">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="toggle" />
      <div class="rds-toggle-header">No</div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just found a bug with this - If I resize while "No" is selected, the offset gets all messed up. Do you know how to resolve that?

Comment: Yes, add a window resize listener, and in its callback function recalculate the offset of the state element. You know how to do that?

Comment: If not, you can also toggle left offset between 0% and 50%, but that will only work for two-way switches (which is what you currently have, yes). My original solution was made to work on multi-option switches as well... See whatever is easier for you and I can help you if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile has a nice Flipswitch that does what you need, if you are ok with using jquery mobile 1.4 in your project.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cou1u6us/9/

jQuery Mobile JS include

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js

HTML

```
<div class="rds-toggle-switch">  
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="checkbox-based-flipswitch">Checkbox-based:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="checkbox-based-flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a slide. It doesn't matter that they're separate elements. Just have a before psuedo-element attached to one of the boxes slide back and forth. In other words...

```
<input type="radio" id="yes" name="test" value="Yes" checked>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="no" name="test" value="No">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

And then a bit of CSS

```
input[type="radio"]{
  position:absolute;
  height:0px;
  width:0px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
  font-style:italic;  
}
label{
  font-size:30px;  
}
#yes::before{
  content:"";
  height:30px;
  width:45px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-5px;
  top:0;
  opacity:1;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
  transform:translateX(100%);
  transition:transform .4s ease-in;
}
#yes:checked::before{
  transform:translateX(0);  
}
```

I've got a pen of it here http://codepen.io/pocketg99/pen/KwreLd

When you submit the form everything will behave as expected.